# How to use custom validators of github.com/1000hz/bootstrap-validator

Tags: javascript, plugins, custom-validators

From the documentation http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/:

> Add custom validators to be run. Validators should be functions that receive the jQuery element as an argument and return a truthy or falsy value based on the validity of the input.
>
> Object structure is: `{foo: function($el) { return true || false } }`
>
> Adding the validator to an input is done just like the others, `data-foo="bar"`.
>
> You must also add default error messages for any custom validators via the errors option.

I don't quite understand how to define my own custom validator and how to use it with this plugin.

Could anyone give me a simple example or hint?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to call your plugin manually, as `custom` options will not work with data-attributes:

```
$().validator({
    custom: {
        'odd': function($el) { return Boolean($el.val() % 2);}
    }
})
```

then use it like this:

```
<input placeholder="plz enter odd value" data-odd>
```

Don't forget to add error messages, [see code](https://github.com/1000hz/bootstrap-validator/blob/master/js/validator.js#L43)

Comment: Note that the custom data-* name must be all lower case or your function will not run for jQuery 1.4+.

Comment: We need to explicitly set it to the form element: `$("#myForm").validator(...);`

Comment: The errors option is no longer used. The validation function is supposed to return an error message if the field is invalid.

Comment: This runs when the form loads, before even pressing submit. Is that by design or have I made an error?

Answer (score 6):

I wanted to flesh out the answers here with a bit more detail.

I was attempting to do this while using the data-api (putting `data-toggle="validator"` in the form tag). Removing that from my `<form>` tag and enabling it with Javascript, my custom function works:

```
$('#sign-up_area').validator({
    custom: {
        'odd': function($el) { return Boolean($el.val() % 2);}
    },
    errors: {
        odd: "That's not an odd number!"
    }
});
```

I also had to add a value to the data-odd attribute thusly:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-12">
        <label class="control-label" for="test">Odd/Even:</label>
        <input type="text" name="test" id="test" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter an odd integer" data-odd="odd" >
        <span class="help-block with-errors"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Interesting to note that if I add the following to the `<input>` element, it takes precedence over the error message declared in javascript:

```
data-odd-error="Not an odd number, yo!"
```

However, I get an error in console if I only use the data-odd-error attribute but NO error message specified in Javascript. Thus, you *must* declare an error message in Javascript.

Answer (score 3):

First of all add your own custom validator, for example:

```
var validatorOptions = {
        delay: 100,
        custom: {
            unique: function ($el) {
                var newDevice = $el.val().trim();
                return isUniqueDevice(newDevice)
            }
        },
        errors: {
            unique: "This Device is already exist"
        }
    }
```

Second, you need to "bind" the form input for the custom validator, for example:

```
<input id="add_new_device_input"  class="form-control"  data-unique="unique">
```

If you want to add to this input more validators error you must to add the custom error to the input: data-unique-error="This device is already exist"
for example:

```
<input id="add_new_device_input"  class="form-control"  data-unique="unique" data-unique-error="This device is already exist" data-error="The Device pattern is invalid" pattern="<Add some regex pattern here>">
```

The "data-error" is the default validator error and it called "native" key, the following code will demonstrate how the validator print the error messages according to the validator key:

```
   function getErrorMessage(key) {
  return $el.data(key + '-error')
    || $el.data('error')
    || key == 'native' && $el[0].validationMessage
    || options.errors[key]
}
```