# Custom validation with github.com/1000hz/bootstrap-validator

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

This question is closely related to:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29759459/how-to-use-custom-validators-of-github-com-1000hz-bootstrap-validator](http://github.com/1000hz/bootstrap-validator)

I'm basically trying to get the custom option to perform some extra validation on a field (beyond the usual data-minlength, required, etc).

The validator works fine under normal circumstances - I've included a test case to demonstrate what I'm trying to do.  It never gets to execute the `console.log('pwc...');` line.

I'd appreciate any pointers.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div>
 <div id="s1">
  <form id="s1Form" data-toggle="validator">
   <input data-pwc="pwc" data-error="Please enter a valid password." data-minlength="6" maxlength="32" id="password" placeholder="Password *" value="123456" required>
   <button id="btn"></button>
  </form>
 </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/validator.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#btn').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
     $('#s1 #s1Form').validator({
         custom: {
             pwc: function(el) {
              // never gets executed:
                 console.log('pwc.....');
                 // tests here, if error then raise error and return false
             }
         }
     });

     if ($('#s1Form').validator('validate').has('.has-error').length) {
      console.log('error');
      return false;
     }
     console.log('proceed...');
 });
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```